# GCM - mensagem não chega e não apresenta erro

Tags: android

https://github.com/analistacarlosh/google_cloud_messaging

Quando dou o send no server me retorna sucesso o envio com sucesso, de acordo com a mensagem a seguir:

```
"{\"multicast_id\":5369005122387463058,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1430508659293017%2eb511def9fd7ecd\"}]}"
```

Mas no celular rodando a App não acontece nada, nenhum erro. Conectado em modo debug com a aplicação sendo executada no Android Studio também nada acontece.

A impressão que tenho é que pelo retorno da parte do server, a mensagem está sendo enviada mas não está encontrando o celular, portanto a não chega a notificação.

Alguém poderia me dar sugestões dos possíveis problemas?

Comment: Você verificou se tudo esta OK con google developers console? O serial number do celular é o mesmo onde o push no server é feito?

Comment: As chaves da sua máquina e do servidor foram geradas?

Comment: Resolvido, estava ok sim estas questões o que aconteceu que no AndroidManifest.xml não coloquei o receiver dentro da tag application, segue referência de como ficou: https://github.com/analistacarlosh/google_cloud_messaging/blob/master/gcm/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Era questão de registrar os services no AndroidManigest.